# Bit shift in array and write score to another array

Tags: c++, c, bit

I write method to bit shift by one in array and save to second array. Let me explain on below example:

```
 unsigned int firstNumber[2]  = { 0x00000001, 0x8FFFFFFF };
 unsigned int resultNumber[2];
```

And result should be:

```
unsigned int resultNumber[2] = { 0x00000000, 0xC7FFFFFF };
```

Below this is my function:

```
void bitShiftByOneInRight_1(unsigned int firstNumber[2], unsigned int resultNumber[2]) 
{
    unsigned int lastBitEnabled = 0;
    unsigned int mask = 1;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        resultNumber[i] = 0;
        //  example        11001101 & 00000001 for uint8_t
        unsigned int lastBit = (firstNumber[i] & mask) << (sizeof(unsigned int)*8 - 1);

        resultNumber[i] = firstNumber[i] >> 1;
        resultNumber[i] = firstNumber[i] | lastBitEnabled;
        lastBitEnabled  = lastBit;
    }
}
```

I get answer as the same array firstNumber[2]:

```
unsigned int resultNumber[2] = { 0x00000001, 0x8FFFFFFF };
```

Simple example, we have array:
 `[0b00000001, 0b01111111]` then answer should be 
 `[0b00000000, 0b10111111]`

Furthermore when function is this form, which mean use one argument as input and output method, work correctly:

```
void bitShiftByOneInRight(unsigned int firstNumber[2]) {
    unsigned int lastBitEnabled = 0;
    unsigned int mask = 1;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

        //  example         11001101 & 00000001 for uint8_t
        unsigned int lastBit = (firstNumber[i] & mask) << (sizeof(unsigned int)*8 - 1);

        firstNumber[i] = firstNumber[i] >> 1;
        firstNumber[i] = firstNumber[i] | lastBitEnabled;
        lastBitEnabled = lastBit;
    }

}
```

Anyone know what I make wrong?
Each answer is welcome for me! Thanks

Comment: C++ clan is at war with the C clan. Choose your side please.

Comment: @RawN Kind of a strange way to put it, but yes. C and C++ are very different languages and you should usually choose only one when tagging your questions. In this case, all the code is valid C.

Comment: Please read about [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @Stargateur A good reason to close for lack of [MCVE].

Comment: What is the idea of this "program"? Shift right with carry to another array element (so in the fact 2x wide word than unsigned)?

Comment: Yes, example [0000001, 01111111] then answer is [00000000, 11111111]

Comment: @Stargateur Yes LENGTH is as 2. My mistake

Comment: More confused than ever, why isn't your commented result `[00000000, 10111111]`?

Comment: @EOF Is lack of mcve actually a sufficient reason to close by StackOverflow rules? I agree that most answerable questions have a mcve and totally am a fan. But there is for example no available flag "lack of MCVE". I agree, a question should either have one or explain why not; but closing with this single reason seems harsh.

Comment: @Weather Vane exactly, you are right! I am to hurry in write comment.

Comment: I recommend making a [mcve]. *(Note the difference that I do not vote for closing for the lack of it.)*

Comment: @tambre "Tag as C++, as the code has initialization lists, which aren't available in C." ??? Where did you see an initialization lists in the OP code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void shift_right(uint32_t *dst, uint32_t *src, size_t len) {
  if (len == 0) return;
  for (size_t i = len - 1; i > 0; i--){
    dst[i] = (src[i] >> 1) | (src[i-1] << 31);
  }  
  dst[0] = src[0] >> 1;
}
```

Comment: ... just a different take on @Gene's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void shift_right(unsigned *dst, unsigned *src, size_t len) {
  if (len == 0) return;
  for (size_t i = len - 1; i > 0; i--) 
    dst[i] = (src[i] >> 1) + (src[i - 1] & 1u) * ~(~0u >> 1);
  dst[0] = src[0] >> 1;
}

int main(void) {
  unsigned int firstNumber[]  = { 0x00000001u, 0x8FFFFFFFu }, secondNumber[2];
  shift_right(secondNumber, firstNumber, 2);
  printf("%08x, %08x", secondNumber[0], secondNumber[1]);
}
```

This can be called with source and destination as the same array.

It works for all widths of `unsigned`.

Although some will question using multiplication, it turns out gcc does a great job of optimizing this to a shift and add that are essentially the same as vicatcu@'s, but auto-adjusted for width.

Comment: `~(~0u >> 1)`, suddenly I discover that they was a simple way to do this.

Comment: That's a standard portable way to set the top bit regardless of how wide the integer is.

Comment: I'm a fan of just using stdint types is the only thing

Answer (score 0):

Did you take the one argument form and tweak it so it has separate input and output arguments? Look more closely at these two lines, they aren't doing what you think at first glance.

```
    resultNumber[i] = firstNumber[i] >> 1;
    resultNumber[i] = firstNumber[i] | lastBitEnabled;
```